# Long string pasted into Eclipse is invisible

Tags: java, eclipse

When pasting the following String into Eclipse, the text shows up as blank spaces:

```
1140002,1210002,1960001,2120002,2140001,3890001,6770002,6800002,7790002,9130002,10230002,12110002,12120002,13660002,14130001,14480002,15540001,15990002,16240002,16720002,16840002,16930002,17180002,18750001,19330001,35170001,39220001,41950001,42120001,43080001,54100001,56410001,65970001,82040001,84530001,84710001,84730001,85010001,85250001,85340001,85630001,85730001,85790001,85930001,85970001,86040001,86370001,86490001,86670001,86680001,86830001,86910001,86940001,87120001,90860001,93220001,97730001,98330001,107400001,110800001,118420001,118830001,118970001,121690001,121710001,122980001,125030001,125040001,125670001,125700001,125860001,125880001,128720001,129000001,130720001,131330001,135460001,140770001,141420001,141720001,142690001,145610001,970001,1400001,1530001,1760001,2020001,2270002,2890001,4150001,5780002,8430002,9150001,9970002,11780002,13860002,14160002,14240002,14490001,14500002,14530002,14850002,15290002,15560002,15690002,16300002,16620001,16660001,17200002,19580001,19790001,39760001,42010001,55540001,56640001,56910001,56920001,57230001,57390001,57420001,57600001,57860001,65690001,74550001,77280001,81340001,81880001,82100001,82920001,83200001,84280001,84350001,84790001,84970001,85260001,85380001,85700001,85980001,86050001,86590001,86600001,86660001,87150001,87360001,87550001,93110001,97540001,102430001,111200001,118880001,119020001,119970001,121700001,123780001,124940001,125000001,125450001,125760001,125790001,128690001,129180001,129980001,129990001,130000001,131340001,133430001,135340001,135470001,135480001,137040001,137140001,137490001,138130001,140050001,140800001,141970001,142460001,142860001,146730001,840002,2630001,3420001,5270001,7830002,9640002,9800002,10040002,10190002,12030002,13090001,14090002,15100002,15380002,15390002,15590002,15790002,15920002,16630001,16640002,17170002,17740001,19460001,55570001,57020001,57130001,57620001,57690001,65450001,66300001,68470001,68680001,69250001,70510001,71930001,72060001,75220001,75890001,77810001,81540001,84870001,84880001,85000001,85130001,85270001,85320001,85410001,85510001,85580001,85750001,85770001,86090001,86110001,86290001,86300001,86460001,86510001,86750001,86770001,87060001,87340001,92850001,94320001,96850001,102900001,103390001,108940001,110710001,112550001,113020001,114550001,118380001,124410001,124840001,124850001,125050001,125780001,125870001,125900001,126690001,128750001,129050001,129270001,130170001,130700001,130730001,132470001,132830001,133480001,133570001,134780001,135930001,135990001,136220001,140060001,141150001,141590001,142480001,143090001,148280001,1200002,2300001,3790001,6870002,7840002,8380002,8420002,8890001,9930002,10030001,10870001,12340001,12680002,12920002,13410002,13520002,14070002,14200002,14280002,14360002,14970001,15310002,15700002,15880002,16310002,16380002,16450002,16750002,16780002,16850002,17610001,18560001,19370001,37820001,40370001,54050001,57000001,58020001,68850001,69740001,75290001,78650001,80290001,83690001,84490001,84580001,84600001,84630001,85120001,85180001,85420001,85670001,85780001,85830001,85870001,86080001,86320001,86390001,86400001,86820001,86920001,87040001,87890001,87910001,94400001,94550001,97030001,97170001,99630001,101570001,109360001,110650001,110860001,110880001,114480001,118930001,119010001,124500001,124520001,125010001,125320001,125340001,125530001,125690001,130760001,131360001,131370001,132910001,133100001,133410001,133530001,133660001,136080001,137070001,141410001,141690001,142470001,142840001,144240001,146680001,147720001,930001,1780001,2520001,5320001,6050002,7970002,8360002,10770002,11360002,13000002,13690002,14270002,14290002,15470002,15520001,15520002,15550002,15670001,15910002,16190002,16610001,16680001,16790002,16860002,16890001,19150001,31990001,35990001,36360001,40790001,41290001,41930001,56460001,56930001,57180001,57190001,65400001,68670001,75340001,76010001,77110001,77460001,83750001,84640001,84840001,86240001,86410001,86430001,86470001,86730001,86790001,86810001,86970001,89300001,93130001,93700001,94070001,97230001,97270001,98040001,100880001,109440001,109480001,114460001,116050001,116250001,117680001,118410001,122960001,122970001,124090001,125080001,125260001,125330001,125550001,125720001,129660001,131320001,133510001,133580001,136000001,138200001,140790001,141240001,141640001,142020001,142440001,144720001,146000001,990001,2270001,2730001,4090002,6340002,8360001,8390002,10290002,11750002,11970001,12640002,13990002,14040002,14250002,15370002,15500002,15770002,16020002,16370002,16900002,17940001,20610001,38190001,44740001,53780001,56390001,57240001,58000001,68460001,69560001,76640001,79280001,81330001,82960001,84570001,84620001,84720001,84740001,85140001,85240001,85400001,85430001,85470001,85480001,85720001,85920001,85940001,86230001,86880001,87080001,87090001,87330001,93090001,93150001,93160001,93250001,94520001,95080001,97210001,110260001,118540001,121180001,121240001,121490001,123810001,124550001,124890001,124920001,125220001,125380001,125500001,125890001,128990001,129500001,129730001,129970001,130710001,130740001,130750001,133370001,133740001,135160001,135890001,137130001,137620001,138180001,138190001,141390001,141710001,143060001,146670001,147640001,750001,990002,1000002,5090002,6460002,6520002,8030002,8320001,9390001,9520001,10840002,11460002,13060002,14140002,14300002,14350002,14370002,14790002,14840002,14940001,15050002,15630002,15860002,16100002,16630002,16650001,16670001,16670002,16700002,17270002,18530001,18710001,32430001,32730001,33310001,43140001,43150001,54090001,55580001,56230001,57060001,57100001,57340001,57440001,57560001,57750001,58120001,65940001,65990001,68480001,69410001,76560001,82860001,83890001,84610001,84910001,85190001,85200001,85330001,85360001,85490001,85540001,85820001,86060001,86520001,86720001,87350001,87580001,93190001,93480001,93870001,97640001,102490001,113010001,114470001,117430001,118960001,118980001,119000001,123140001,124960001,125060001,125070001,125250001,125310001,125430001,125510001,125680001,125730001,125770001,125910001,128930001,131390001,132020001,133490001,133500001,133550001,133600001,135450001,136020001,138210001,138600001,140740001,141570001,141660001,141670001,142140001,142450001,142620001,142630001,143120001,147730001,148490001,1100002,1900001,3200002,6760002,10050002,13700002,15030002,15780001,16260002,16650002,16950001,20480001,37830001,38640001,42030001,45300001,54040001,57090001,57580001,75450001,76920001,84130001,84220001,84800001,84810001,84850001,84940001,84980001,85070001,85080001,85220001,85310001,85600001,85840001,85890001,85910001,86650001,86860001,86890001,87050001,93070001,93440001,93750001,94250001,94980001,96360001,99620001,101400001,109000001,109340001,112210001,116140001,118990001,122790001,123200001,124390001,124930001,125410001,125540001,125710001,125740001,128610001,128780001,129040001,129320001,131400001,132270001,132940001,133440001,133670001,135440001,135880001,135900001,135980001,137050001,137060001,140170001,140780001,140970001,141380001,142130001,143020001,143210001,145920001,148300001
```

Interestingly, this only happens inside the main method of my program, but not when pasted outside the main class.

Why is it that this long string becomes totally invisible when pasted inside the main method, and how can I go about pasting this string into my program?

Comment: Same for me, Eclipse 4.5.0, seems to happen in Java files but not TXT files

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+V doesn't work for me unfortunately. I guess I can always just read the text from a file and create a string that way. Still doesn't solve the Eclipe problem!

Comment: If you need that data in your program, why don't you read it from a file?

Comment: If you highlight the text that you have pasted does it show up? It might just be your editor colour options having the same text and background colour.

Comment: It's invisible still. When I paste it outside of the main method for whatever reason I can see it, but not inside my program.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose in cases like this it would be wiser to just read a .txt file containing the desired data and then write it to a String. I was just curious as to why Eclipse doesn't accept long strings into Java programs. Anyway:

```
        String myCurrentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        String textDir = myCurrentDir + "\\" + MyClass.class.getName().toString() + ".txt";
        // System.out.println(textDir);

        File f = new File(textDir);
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(f);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) f.length()];
        new DataInputStream(fin).readFully(buffer);
        fin.close();
        String commaString = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
```